# Swift add object in to AnyObject

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I need add an object into AnyObject

```
let swiftArray: [String: AnyObject] = ["one": "asd", "two": "asd", "three": "asd"]
```

How to add more objects?

Like,

```
let swiftArray: [String: AnyObject] = ["one": "asd", "two": "asd", "three": "asd"]
print(swiftArray)

swiftArray.append("test": "test") // NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Hint: array ≠ dictionary

Comment: i mean doing this doesn't work? `swiftArray[test] = "test"`?

Answer (score 4):

Swift syntax is rather confusing. You are actually trying to create a Dictionary instead.

To use an Array:

```
var swiftArray: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
swiftArray.append("test")
```

--> Notice that you must use `var` instead of `let` for the Array to be mutable.

To use a Dictionary:

```
var swiftDict: [String: String] = ["one": "value"]
swiftDict["newElement"] = "newValue"
```

Please throughly read the Swift 2.1 documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read up on how swift works!!!

I'm gonna hold your hand on this one, and show you all the things that are off here.

FIRST, you're declaring your variable with a `let` statement, which creates **Immutable** variables (i.e., they can't change!). If you'd like to create a variable that can change, user `var ...`, so

```
var swiftDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["one": "asd", "two": "asd", "three": "asd"]
```

SECOND, what you're thinking of here is a **dictionary**, not an **array**. Arrays can be thought of as lists, or stacks of data, where each piece of data has a number, and is stacked on the last piece of data. A dictionary is more like a pool of data, where each piece has a name, or key, you call to retrieve it.

Rule of thumb, if you're got values tied together, you've got a dictionary.

THIRD, it's really easy to add to a dict, just use the following syntax.

```
swiftDict["four"] = "asd"
```

If you're still confused, try google, and feel free to ask for more info.